# issues with getting input from user

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api

I wrote a program that can find a distance between two points using google's api. I sorted most of the issues but there is only one issue reminiscing i.e if user enters any random words and numbers then i am getting error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'.

Basically I want to check whether user enters only city name or cityname, state(like MA, NY etc) and program should reject rest of the input.

How can i fix this issues?

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

from geopy.distance import vincenty

from geopy.distance import great_circle

geolocator = Nominatim()
try:
    #Asking user for input 
    Location = raw_input('Enter the Final location in the format of ctiyname or cityname state name, please avoid "," to separte cityname and statename :-') 
    #New line char
    print "\n"
except:
    #Printing error message 
    print "location not found"
    #Using "raise SystemExit" for program termination if file not found
    raise SystemExit
location_2 = geolocator.geocode(Location)
#Getting the coordinates of users location
coord_2 = (location_2.latitude, location_2.longitude)
#using static location
Location_1 = 'Hoboken'
#static location coordinates 
coord_1 = (40.7433066, -74.0323751)

print "The static location is",Location_1,"and its geographical coordinates are",coord_1,"\n"

print "The target location is ",Location,"and its geographical coordinates are",coord_2,"\n"

print "The distance between the two destinations by 'Vincenty distance' method in miles is :",(vincenty (coord_1, coord_2).miles),"\n"

print "The distance between the two destinations by 'great_circle'method in miles is :",(great_circle (coord_1, coord_2).miles),"\n"
```

Comment: Why not just check if .latitude is None and if it is print that it's an invalid location. You don't need to bother with figuring out if an address is valid if your api already does it for you

Comment: I think You should consider first if your program task is to validate user input against truth of the provided data (if it is a real localisation etc...). You could simply return an error with explanation that provided localisation is not truth, other way You could consider using some source to check user input against your data source checked localisation and not allow him to proceed.